# java spring pattern match String

Tags: java, regex

i have a pattern to get

```
String string = "max_len[5];"
```

the number 5 can be anything for 0-9

now i need to check if max_len is a pattern  then if it is i need to get the 5

```
if(string = "max_len" //regex){
  int = regex for the number 5;
}
```

Comment: *"check if max_len is a pattern"* - what is that supposed to mean? Is .* a pattern in your terms?

Comment: basically  i have a sting  which is "max_len[4]"       no i need to check whether  the sting consists of the word "max_len"

Comment: Can't you just use a simple reg ex tutorial for Java? it should be as simple as `max_len\[(\d)\]`... I leave it to you how to use that reg ex in Java :)

Comment: @xander cheers i used it ... i'm horrible at reg_ex i can never seem to write a regex     iv never written a reg_ex my self  in any php|python|java|Js i always rely on some regex builder :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you go through a [tutorial on regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) since that would both help you solve your problem but more importantly understand how you should solve similar problems in the future.

Anyways, you want to use Java's [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for this to match *max_len* and extract the number at the same time. Here's how you do it:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("max_len\[(?<maxLength>\d)\];");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(string);
if (match.matches()) {
    int maxLength = Integer.parseInt(match.group("maxLength"));
    print("The maximum length is " + match.group("maxLength"));
} else {
    print("The string didn't match the pattern");
}
```

The pattern breaks down into the following:

- `max_len\[` matches the string *max_len[*
- `(?<maxLength>\d)` Creates a match group named maxLength that matches any single digit
- `\];` matches the string *];*

You can get a more thorough breakdown of the regular expression over at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yNAPGr/1) where you can also play around with it and try out which input strings will match and which will not.

If we get a successful match we can extract the value of group named *maxLength* and parse it as an integer. We know that it is safe to parse as an integer without catching any exceptions because the pattern will only match if it's a digit, so the string *max_length[five];* will cause `match.matches()` to return `false`.

If you want to allow larger numbers that single digits you can change `\d` to `\d+`. The plus means that any number of digits, but at least one, will be matched. If you use an asterisk (***) instead you will match any number of digits, including no digits which will cause `Integer.parseInt` to throw an exception because an empty string (`""`) is not a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

Here your regex you want :

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main( String args[] ) {
      // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
      String line = "max_len[5];";
      String pattern = "^max_len\\[(\\d+)\\];$";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      if (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
      }else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
String regex = "^max_len\\[(\\d+)\\];$";
String stringPattern = "max_len[5];";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringPattern);
if(matcher.find()){
    int maxLength = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String string = "max_len[9]";
String number = string.replaceFirst("^max_len\\[(\\d)\\]$", "$1");
if (!number.equals(string)) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(number);
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

result

```
9
```